# Two Vf pages, one controller

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, controller-extension, redirect

I have Vf pages on Opportunity and contact.i have continue button to redirect opportunity vf to contact vf.  i want to auto-populate fields from opportunity vf page to contact vf page. i'm using one controller when i use controller in contact vf page it  shoes error . new to salesforce, any suggestions?
(ignore other methods )
 Contact owner and account name should auto-populate

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="opportunityOrderDetail" >
<apex:form >
  <apex:messages />
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity details"  >

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportnuity Infromation" >
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.OwnerId }" />
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Name }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Account.Name }"/>

        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Opportunity.Order_Details__c}" >
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!check}" reRender="AddInfoSection"  />  
        </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:pageBlockSection> 
    <apex:outputPanel id="wrapperPannel" layout="none"  >  
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Additional Information" id="AddInfoSection" rendered="{!showInfo}">
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.OrderNumber__c }" /> 
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.MainCompetitors__c }"   /> 
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.DeliveryInstallationStatus__c }"  />
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.TrackingNumber__c }"   /> 
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:outputPanel> 

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Description Information">
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Opportunity.ReadOnly__c}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ReadOnlyCheckBox}" reRender="ReadOnlySection"  />
    </apex:inputCheckbox> <br/>
    <apex:inputTextarea value="{! Opportunity.Description }" id="ReadOnlySection" disabled="{!Readval}"/> <br/>
    <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Reason_for_Rejection__c}"/> 

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >

        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="cancel"/>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!continueButton}" value="Continue"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

opportunityOrderDetail Controller

```
public with sharing class  opportunityOrderDetail{
public Opportunity oppty{get;set;}
public Boolean showInfo{get;set;}
public Boolean Readval{get;set;}
public Contact con{get;set;}
private ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl;
public  opportunityOrderDetail(ApexPages.StandardController std){
    showInfo=false;
    Readval=false;
    stdCtrl=std;
    Opportunity oppty=(Opportunity)stdCtrl.getRecord(); 
    }   
public pagereference  autopop(){
    Contact cont=(Contact)stdCtrl.getRecord();
    cont.AccountId=[SELECT ID,Name FROM Opportunity where Id=:Oppty.AccountId];
    return null;

}
public pagereference check(){  
    if(showInfo ==true){ 
       showInfo=false; 
     } 
     else{ 
         showInfo= true; 
     } 

    return null; 
 } 
public pagereference ReadOnlyCheckBox(){
   if (Readval==true){
            Readval=false;
            }else{Readval=true;
                }
            return null;
            }           

public pagereference BackButton(){
    return Page.OppView;
 }
public pagereference continueButton(){
   return Page.RedirectDetailPage;
```

}

}

Contact Vf page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact"  extensions="opportunityOrderDetail" 
 action="{!autopop}" >
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Contact Details ">
     <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.OwnerId}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Account.Name}" /> 

        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.FirstName}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.LastName}" />






    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
 <apex:commandButton action="{!BackButton}" value="Back"/>  
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="cancel"/>

    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  </apex:pageBlock>


</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your redirecting to contact VF page, standardController is look for Id of the contact. You have set contact id to page reference.

Make sure **cont** is not null before redirecting page.

```
public pagereference continueButton(){
   PageReference pageRef = new  Page.RedirectDetailPage;
   pageRef.setRedirect(true);
   pageRef.getParameters().put('id',cont.id);
   return pageRef;
}
```